# Is there any way to avoid combining many tests into one example, when using mocks?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec

Partly following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372763/rspec-how-do-i-write-a-test-that-expects-certain-output-but-doesnt-care-about-t) question.  Hopefully the example speaks for itself: there's a WishlistReporter class which asks one object for data and outputs to another object.

The problem is that with the double for DB, I'm actually testing a whole bunch of things in a single example.  Which is not ideal.

I can split the report() method into gather_data() and output() methods.  But that doesn't help: in order to test the output() method I would still need to create the mock db and run gather_data() again.

Is there a way around this?

```
describe WishlistReporter do

  it "should talk to the DB and output a report" do
    db = double("database")
    db.should_receive(:categories).and_return(["C1"])
    db.should_receive(:items).with("C1").and_return(["I1", "I2"])
    db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I1").and_return(["S1", "S2"])
    db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I2").and_return(["S3", "S4"])

    wr = StringIO.new

    r = WishlistReporter.new(db)
    r.report(db, :text, wr)

    wr.seek(0)
    wr.read.should =~ /stuff/
  end
end
```

(In reference to the previous question:  I'm perfectly happy to mock the Db class because I consider its interface to be external: part of the "what" not the "how".)

Comment: Looks like I'm just going to live with it.

Comment: ...but lets try a bounty, just to see if we can get any other opinions onboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sort of situation, I wouldn't verify the calls to @db because those are read-only calls, so I really don't care if they happen or not.  Yes, of course they do have to happen (otherwise where is the data coming from), but I don't think of it as an explicit requirement on the behavior of WishlistReporter... If WishlistReporter could produce the report without talking to the database that'd be perfectly fine by me.

I would use `db.stub!` instead of `db.should_receive` and be perfectly happy with that.

But for cases where the calls to the object being mocked have side-effects and *are* explicit requirements, I do something like this.  (In this example, for whatever reason we require that the db object be instructed to reload its data before we query it.)  Again, the methods that are returning the data don't need to be explicitly verified, since if the report output is correct, then the data must have been pulled from @db correctly:

```
describe WishlistReporter do

  before(:each) do
    @db = double("database")
    @db.stub!(:reload_data_from_server)
    @db.stub!(:categories).and_return(["C1"])
    @db.stub!(:items).with("C1").and_return(["I1", "I2"])
    @db.stub!(:subitems).with("I1").and_return(["S1", "S2"])
    @db.stub!(:subitems).with("I2").and_return(["S3", "S4"])
    @output = StringIO.new
    @subject = WishlistReporter.new(@db)
  end

  it "should reload data before generating a report" do
    @db.should_receive(:reload_data_from_server)

    @subject.report(:text, @output)
  end

  it "should output a report" do
    @subject.report(:text, @output)

    @output.seek(0)
    @output.read.should =~ /stuff/
  end
end
```

Comment: Damn: you're right.  I shouldn't care where Reporter gets the data from.  Which makes my `expect`s into `stub`s, which makes more sense of Solnic's answer, too.  I'm going to note that the situation I describe above is a "spec code smell".  And that `expects` can code you into some nasty corners if you are not careful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I always add this kind of expectations to a before block. I'd write your spec like this:

```
describe WishlistReporter do
  let(:db) { double('database') }
  let(:wf) { StringIO.new }

  subject { WishListReporter.new(db) }

  describe '#read' do
    before do
      db.should_receive(:categories).and_return(["C1"])
      db.should_receive(:items).with("C1").and_return(["I1", "I2"])
      db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I1").and_return(["S1", "S2"])
      db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I2").and_return(["S3", "S4"])

      subject.report(db, :text, wr)
      subject.seek(0)
    end

    it 'talks to the DB and outputs a report' do
      subject.read.should =~ /stuff/
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm.  If one of those should_receives fails, what does rspec show?  Ideally I'd like those examples to be associated with a test description...

Comment: A failure coming from this before hook will be associated with the example. You will see a meaningful output.

Comment: well, that's good to know.  But that means it's functionally the same as my code in the question.  All those tests, but all associated with one example.

Comment: Right, although it is a good practice to set up context of your test in a before block. So basically your "it" block should only check if the output of #read method is correct. Everything else should be inside "before", that includes #should_receive too.

Comment: Surely should_receive isn't just context, it's actually a test?  I suppose it just depends how you see it...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, again!  Here's one way to solve the problem, but frankly I think that for me, the cure is worse than the disease.

```
describe WishlistReporter do
  before(:each) do
    @db = double("database")
    @wr = WishlistReporter.new(db)
  end

  describe "#gather_data" do        
    it "should talk to the DB" do
      @db.should_receive(:categories).and_return(["C1"])
      @db.should_receive(:items).with("C1").and_return(["I1", "I2"])
      @db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I1")
      @db.should_receive(:subitems).with("I2")
      @wr.gather_data
    end
  end

  describe "#report" do
    it "should output a report" do
      @wr.should_receive(:gather_data).and_return( {"C1"=>{"I1"=>["S1", "S2"], "I2"=> etc etc}})
      file = StringIO.new

      @wr.report(:text, file)

      wr.seek(0)
      wr.read.should =~ /stuff/
    end
  end

end
```

I think the point here is I've just introduced a massive complexity in the code to make the example a bit simpler.  That's not a trade-off I feel comfortable with.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is besides the point, but I think your code is structured in a strange way. Instead of expecting the code to call

```
categories = db.categories
categories.each do |category| 
  items = db.items(category) 
  items.each do |item|
    db.subitems(item)
  end
end
```

I would expect it to call:

```
categories = db.categories
categories.each do |category| 
  items = category.items
  items.each do |item|
    item.subitems
  end
end
```

A category object has items. You shouldn't need to pass a category object to a db object to get at its items. Either you're not using ActiveRecord (or DataMapper, or ...) or you're using it in a strange way.

Then you could do:

```
let(:items) {[mock('item1', :subitems => ["S1", "S2"]), 
              mock('item2', :subitems => ["S3", "S4"])]}
let(:categories) {[mock('category', :items => items)]}
let(:db) {double('database', :categories => categories)}
```

which sidesteps having to name all the stuff and shares the stubs between all specs. These are stubs, not expectations, but as this is not the core functionality you're testing, I agree with Aaron V. that stubs are more appropriate.

---

Edit after responding to comments and re-reading the question:

Your main complaint in the question is that

> with the double for DB, I'm actually testing a whole bunch of things in a single example

To me that indicated that your problem was with the double, because that is presented as the reason you are 'testing a while bunch of things'. Perhaps you don't like the expectations (which can be a way of testing things that binds the test very closely to the implementation), the chained list to get it working or a perceived need to repeat them. All of that makes sense and your own answer, using chained expectations, reflects the wish for a simplification in the way the double is being used.

However, when reading it carefully once more, the actual problem turns out to be about splitting some method into two other methods and testing them separately. Unfortunately, that line of reasoning is not supported by the example at all. It has nothing to do with the double or the expectations and you could have left them out without a problem. You are very familiar with your code and your problem and this may all seem obvious to you, but to me, as a casual reader of your question, it isn't.

Now as to your problem: if your problem is indeed that you feel that splitting `report()` into two functions is pointless, because you can't test `output()` separately from `gather_data()`, because `gather_data()` needs to be called to produce the input for `output()`, then you are forgetting two things:

1. Splitting code into separate functions is always a good idea, if the code can be logically divided into those functions . It makes the code easier to understand, easier to maintain and more effectively testable. The last, because:
2. Even if you can't test `output()` separately from `gather_data()`, you can still test `gather_data()` separately. That test will give you earlier warnings about a smaller piece of code, which makes it easier to identify and solve problems.

The related problem, that you feel you can't test `output()` separately from `gather_data()`, is not a problem that is generally solvable. In every case, you've got three choices:

1. You mock the literal input to `output()` and test it in an isolated fashion, based on that input (and usually some variations, to test multiple code paths).
2. You write a mock version of gather_data() that partly duplicates it's logic, but is much simpler to reason about and call that one to produce input for `output()`.
3. You test `gather_data()` and `output()` together, because pragmatically it's too much trouble to test `output()` in isolation.

`gather_data()` needs input and you either supply it by hand, by a script or by the code that produces it anyway. The last one is a perfectly acceptable pragmatic solution, assuming you have a separate test of `gather_data()` that already tells you whether the combined test failed because `gather_data()` failed or because `output()` failed.

Comment: -1.  You've made unfounded assumptions about my code, I'm afraid.  (There is nothing weird about not using ActiveRecord, by the way, although I happen to be doing so.)  The problem lies not in how I am accessing the database (pretty much as you suggest yourself, in fact) but whether I can seperate the tests on the functionality that organises the data into a report, from the tests on the functionality that outputs the report.  I could indeed use the `let` statements you describe.  They would have no effect on my problem whatsoever.

Comment: Having read Aaron's answer I see that my problem was with expect.  So those `let`s would in fact have helped.  But the key point was that I was trying to test something that I shouldn't have cared about.

Comment: Unfounded assumptions? Your expectations literally say you expect the db object to have a function named items that is to be called with a category instance. That is uncommon to say the least. How is that an assumption? As far as I can see, it's all there in your code.

Comment: Contrary to your expectations, which will fail if the implementation changes, the let statements using stubs do not test anything and will support more variations of the code that is called in the spec. This certainly affects your problem that you feel too much is being tested in a single spec. Expectations test things, stubs don't.